# How to show different number of graph between the options of a PopupMenu (within Manipulate)?

Tags: plotting

I have the following code. My question is: how do I do so that when I choose the first option the s orbital and its graph appear; in the second option, the p orbitals and their graph; and in the following options, the rest of the orbitals (d and f) with their respective graphs?

```
fs[theta_, phi_] := (1/Sqrt[2]*1/Sqrt[2*Pi])^2;
fpx[theta_, phi_] := (Sqrt[3]*Sin[theta]/2*Cos[phi]/Sqrt[Pi])^2;
fpy[theta_, phi_] := (Sqrt[3]*Sin[theta]/2*Sin[phi]/Sqrt[Pi])^2;
fpz[theta_, phi_] := (Sqrt[6]*Cos[theta]/2*1/Sqrt[2*Pi])^2;

Manipulate[Row[{
   SphericalPlot3D[Orbital[theta, phi], {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2*Pi},
    PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotStyle -> {{Pink, Directive[Opacity[0.5]]}, {Pink, 
       Directive[Opacity[0.5]]}}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific",
    AxesLabel -> {Style[x, Medium], Style[y, Medium], 
      Style[z, Medium]}, AxesStyle -> GrayLevel[0.3],
    Mesh -> 50, MeshStyle -> Opacity[0.2], ImageSize -> Medium],
   Plot[Integrate[Orbital[theta, phi], {phi, 0, 2*Pi}], {theta, 0, Pi},
    PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thickness[0.003]}},
    Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"\[Theta]", "\[CapitalGamma]"}, 
    FrameStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.30], 11],
    RotateLabel -> False, ImageSize -> Medium]
   }],
 {{Orbital, fs}, {
   fs -> "s",
   fpx -> "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(x\)]\)",
   fpy -> "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(y\)]\)",
   fpz -> "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(z\)]\)"
   }, ControlType -> PopupMenu}]
```

I have tried several ways, but so far I can't get it.

Comment: What is wrong? It seems to work, s and p orbitals appear. d and f are not implemented.

Comment: I would like all three p orbitals to appear together. I didn't put the d and f orbitals for reasons of space, but the idea is the same.

Comment: Manipulate variable values can also be lists, so: ``{Orbital, {fs}}, {{fs} -> "s", {fpx, fpy, fpz} -> "p"}``. Then, use [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) over ``Orbital`` to show multiple plots, so instead of ``Orbital[theta, phi]`` use ``Evaluate[#[theta, phi] & /@ Orbital]`` and ``Evaluate[Integrate[#[theta, phi], {phi, 0, 2*Pi}] & /@ Orbital]``. Furthermore, I suggest precomputing the integrals for better performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your example with s and p orbitals:

```
fs[theta_, phi_] := (1/Sqrt[2]*1/Sqrt[2*Pi])^2;
fpx[theta_, phi_] := (Sqrt[3]*Sin[theta]/2*Cos[phi]/Sqrt[Pi])^2;
fpy[theta_, phi_] := (Sqrt[3]*Sin[theta]/2*Sin[phi]/Sqrt[Pi])^2;
fpz[theta_, phi_] := (Sqrt[6]*Cos[theta]/2*1/Sqrt[2*Pi])^2;

disp[Orbital_] := 
 SphericalPlot3D[Orbital[theta, phi], {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2*Pi}, 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Pink, Directive[Opacity[0.5]]}, {Pink, 
     Directive[Opacity[0.5]]}}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
  AxesLabel -> {Style[x, Medium], Style[y, Medium], Style[z, Medium]},
   AxesStyle -> GrayLevel[0.3], Mesh -> 50, MeshStyle -> Opacity[0.2],
   ImageSize -> Medium]

Manipulate[
 Switch[Orbital
  , s, disp[fs]
  , p, Row[disp /@ {fpx, fpy, fpz}]
  ]
 , {{Orbital, s}, {s -> "s", p -> "p"}, ControlType -> PopupMenu}]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Using [`TogglerBar`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TogglerBar.html) rather than [`PopupMenu`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PopupMenu.html) provides greater flexibility.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

fs[theta_, phi_] :=
  (1/Sqrt[2]*1/Sqrt[2*π])^2;
fpx[theta_, phi_] :=
  (Sqrt[3]*Sin[theta]/2*Cos[phi]/Sqrt[π])^2;
fpy[theta_, phi_] :=
  (Sqrt[3]*Sin[theta]/2*Sin[phi]/Sqrt[π])^2;
fpz[theta_, phi_] :=
  (Sqrt[6]*Cos[theta]/2*1/Sqrt[2*π])^2;

funcs[t_, p_] = Through[{fs, fpx, fpy, fpz}[t, p]];

ints[t_] = Integrate[funcs[t, p], {p, 0, 2*π}];
```

Plotting,

```
Manipulate[Module[{f, legends,
   colors = {Lighter[Blue, 0.5], Red, Green, Darker[Orange, 0.2]}},
  Orbital =
   If[Orbital === {}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, Sort[Orbital]];
  f = funcs[theta, phi][[Orbital]];
  legends = {HoldForm[s], HoldForm[Subscript[p, x]],
     HoldForm[Subscript[p, y]], HoldForm[Subscript[p, z]]}[[
     Orbital]];
  Column[{
    SphericalPlot3D[Evaluate[f],
     {theta, 0, π}, {phi, 0, 2*π},
     PlotRange -> 1/4, PlotStyle ->
      (Opacity[0.5, #] & /@ colors)[[Orbital]],
     PlotTheme -> "Scientific",
     AxesLabel -> (Style[#, Medium] & /@ {"x", "y", "z"}),
     AxesStyle -> GrayLevel[0.3],
     Mesh -> 50, MeshStyle -> Opacity[0.2],
     ImageSize -> Medium, PlotLegends -> legends],
    Plot[Evaluate[ints[theta]], {theta, 0, π},
     PlotRange -> {-0.05, 1.55}, Frame -> True,
     FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {"θ", "Γ"}),
     FrameStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.30], 11],
     RotateLabel -> False, ImageSize -> Medium,
     PlotLegends -> legends, PlotStyle ->
      (colors[[Orbital]] /. Green :> {Dashed, Green})]}]],
 {{Orbital, {1, 2, 3, 4}}, {1 -> HoldForm[s],
   2 -> HoldForm[Subscript[p, x]],
   3 -> HoldForm[Subscript[p, y]],
   4 -> HoldForm[Subscript[p, z]]},
  ControlType -> TogglerBar}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This will help me with another problem I have with Manipulate: graphing hybrid orbitals.